# SQL Update set from another table where fields are not equal

Tags: sql, sql-update

Let's say I have 2 tables `USER1(id, first, last)` and `USER2(id, first, last)`. I want to write a query to update `USER1` by selecting from `USER2` on 1.id = 2.id and only update the fields, which are different. For example, only update first when first(s) are different. Please help.

Comment: Update syntax like this tends to differ from Database to database. Which one are you using? Sql Server, Oracle, MySql?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't explain my question correctly. I just edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Update User1 
     set 
          u1.first= select 
                        case when u2.first<>u1.first then u2.first 
                             else u1.first end,
          u1.last=  select 
                        case when u2.last<>u1.last then u2.last 
                             else u1.last end
from User1 as u1
outer apply 
     (
        select ui2.first, ui2.last 
        from User2 as ui2 
        where (ui2.first<>u1.first or ui2.last<>u1.last )
     ) 
        as u2 
where u2.Id=u1.Id
```

Comment: Sorry, i didn't explain my question correctly. I just edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to venture into OUTER APPLY, you can do the same thing with a simple join, they are often easier on the query optimizer.

And concerning your edit isolating column changes, I'm pretty sure you gain nothing by considering first name and last name updates in separate cases. I'm not sure about DB2, but MS SQL processes an UPDATE by deleting the row and inserting it back in with the new values, so updating both first and last costs the same as updating either one alone. Putting them in 2 cases doubles the code you have to maintain and costs double when both first and last change for the same record.

```
DECLARE @User1 TABLE (ID int, [First] varchar(50), [Last] varchar(50))
DECLARE @User2 TABLE (ID int, [First] varchar(50), [Last] varchar(50))

INSERT INTO @User1 VALUES (1, 'Alice', 'Smith'), (2, 'Bill', 'Brown'), (3, 'Chuck', 'Calvert')
INSERT INTO @User2 VALUES (1, 'Alice', 'Aarons'), (2, 'Bob', 'Brown'), (4, 'Charlie', 'Calvert')

SELECT * FROM @User1
SELECT * FROM @User2

UPDATE @User1 
SET [First] = U2.[First], [Last] = U2.[Last] 
FROM @User1 as U1 inner join @User2 as U2 on U1.ID = U2.ID 
WHERE U1.[First] != U2.[First] OR U1.[Last] != U2.[Last]

SELECT * FROM @User1
SELECT * FROM @User2
```

Comment: Thanks! I only want to update the fields that are diff. I only want to update first when first(s) are different and not touching the last if last(s) are the same. Will your query do that?

Comment: Got it! Please just ignore my last question. THX!